# Settings file from winforms in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, winforms, settings

I have in winforms app definied settings in user scope. I have used default for winforms settings file (*.settings extension). But now I'm trying to change the presentation layer from winforms to asp.net page. Is this possible to use the same settings in an asp.net? Now I have got only an exception. The settings are stored in an app.config file and VS generated a wrapper for that which works ok only in winforms. I need to have possibility to operate on the same file from winforms and asp.net presentation layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [profile provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5.aspx) to store user settings and preferences. Otherwise you could home bake something... Although I would go with profiles myself.